# Настройка сервиса WCF через файл конфигурации

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Не получается правильно настроить работу сервиса через файл конфигурации. Видимо не правильно настраиваю endpoint mex.
Сейчас конфигурация такая:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
</startup>

<system.serviceModel>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="TelemetryData">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<services>
  <service name="TelemetryService.TelemetryData" 
   behaviorConfiguration="TelemetryData">
    <endpoint name="realData" address="http://localhost:8000/ITelemetryContract/" 
              binding="netHttpBinding"
              contract="GeneralContract.ITelemetryContract"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>

</system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

При запуске сыпятся ошибки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если убрать сточку

```
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
```

То все начинает работать. Но... В клиент сервис не добавляется по ссылке (Connected services - Add service reference). Только если в сервисе сделать следующее:

```
Uri address = new Uri(connectionString);            // ADDRESS;
NetHttpBinding binding = new NetHttpBinding();       // BINDING;    
Type contract = typeof(ITelemetryContract);          // CONTRACT; 

ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(TelemetryData));
host.AddServiceEndpoint(contract, binding, address);
host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceMetadataBehavior());
host.AddServiceEndpoint(ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName, MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding(), "http://localhost:8000/ITelemetryContract/mex");
```

В этом случае сервис добавляется по ссылке.
Хотелось бы настроить все через файл конфигурации, для гибкости.

Comment: Покажите секцию `bindings` в app.conf (и netHttpBinding и mexHttpBinding)

Comment: Выше вся конфигурация на стороне клиента.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем всем спасибо, изучив ответы и комментарии сделал следующее:

```
      <service name="TelemetryService.TelemetryData" behaviorConfiguration="TelemetryData">
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/ITelemetryContract/" />
      </baseAddresses>
```

Все сразу заработало. И сервис запустился, и в браузере отрендерился и с клиентом связался, и по ссылке в клиент добавился.

Comment: Фактически, вы заменили адрес для второй конечной точки. Не обязательно это делать через baseAddresses - можно и сразу в атрибуте address указывать полный URL. Но ошибка в формате URL никак не могла приводить к ошибке на скриншоте, после указания behaviorConfiguration ошибка обязана была измениться!

Comment: Ошибка возникала после добавления строки `<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />` И без этой строки сервис работал behaviorConfiguration="TelemetryData". Не знаю, но реально когда начал шагать в коде, хост просто ловил null в строке подключения.

Comment: Павел правильно говорит, что текст ошибки просто обязан был измениться, потому что его ответ реально исправлял именно эту ошибку. Но у вас в вопросе по факту смешались две темы - поэтому вам нужно понимать, что один вопрос вы решили, а второй где-то проскочили на честном слове, а не на понимании.

Comment: Ребят подскажите пожалуйста. Ситуация такая, создал сервис подобный, один в один, только с другим контрактом. Адрес такой же, кроме порта. Запускаю сервис, в клиенте добавляю ссылку (видит контракт, его методы и тд), а файл app.config не изменяется. В браузере объектов он есть, но пустой. Добавляю старый сервис (тот что в вопросе описывал), все заводится, файл изменяется и тд...

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте вашему сервису атрибут `behaviorConfiguration="TelemetryData"`. Без него у вас сервис сам по себе, а его поведение - само по себе...

Comment: Добавил <service name="TelemetryService.TelemetryData" behaviorConfiguration="TelemetryData"> Ошибки идут...

Comment: @JDo какие именно?

Comment: Те что на скриншоте в самом вопросе. Но уже не актуально.

Comment: В общем-то это именно тот ответ, который отвечал на основную проблему - что не было связи сервиса с поведением. Это уже осталось в старой версии вопроса, но текст ошибки именно об этом.

Answer (score 1):

Не в качестве ответа, просто чтобы не вставлять код в комментариях:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="MEX" name="MyCompanyName.MyProjectName.Service.ServiceProviders.Service">
        <endpoint address="tinyurl" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpNoSecurity" name="MainEndpoint" contract="MyCompanyName.MyProjectName.Contracts.ServiceContracts.IService" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8050/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpNoSecurity" closeTimeout="00:02:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="512000">
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="5000000" />
          <security mode="None"></security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MEX">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Обратите внимание на секцию bindings: у вас её нет.

А это:

> То все начинает работать. Но... В клиент сервис не добавляется по
>   ссылке

```
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MEX">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
```

см. в msdn [httpGetEnabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.servicemodel.description.servicemetadatabehavior.httpgetenabled(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Секция bindings не обязательна если используются настройки привязки по умолчанию. Что же до `httpGetEnabled` - не вижу никаких отличий от того что написано в вопросе (имя для behavior это как имя переменной, оно может быть любым).

Comment: @PavelMayorov А вы правы. Никогда ранее не задумывался о том, что можно биндинги опустить, теперь буду знать.